# Refresh core-ajax periodically using setTimeout and go();

Tags: ajax, settimeout, polymer

I have a core-ajax component that is working fine (I see all the expected data):

```
  <template is="auto-binding">
      <core-ajax id="ds" auto url="https://server/data.json" response="{{data}}"></core-ajax>
    <my-alarms alarms="{{data}}"></mu-alarms>
  </template>
```

I'm attempting to refresh it periodically just for a proof of concept demo using the following javascript:

```
function f() {
    $('#ds').go();
}
setTimeout(f, 1000)
```

This results in the following error on the line with go()

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

[Here is the documentation.](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-ajax)  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that function looks like jquery. try this.

```
function f() {
  document.querySelector("#ds").go();
}
setTimeout(f, 1000);
```

not real sure about using jquery with polymer. i think it can't find elements in shadowdom like using document.querySelector can.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a Map not a function in Polymer. It available only in Polymer elements and you can use it like

```
function f() {
    $.ds.go();
}
setTimeout(f, 1000)
```

to access elements inside the elements shadowDOM.

Comment: `$` won't be available outside of Polymer. You'll want to use `document.querySelector('#ds').go()`